# Why this boost thread creation does't compile?

Tags: multithreading, boost, bind

I wrote some multithreading code using Boost thread library. I initialized two threads in the constructor using the placeholder _1 as the argument required by member function fillSample(int num). But this doesn't compile in my Visual Studio 2010.  Following is the code:

```
#include<boost/thread.hpp>
#include<boost/thread/condition.hpp>
#include<boost/bind/placeholders.hpp>

#define SAMPLING_FREQ 250
#define MAX_NUM_SAMPLES 5*60*SAMPLING_FREQ
#define BUFFER_SIZE 8

class ECG
{
private:
    int sample[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int sampleIdx;
    int readIdx, writeIdx;
    boost::thread m_ThreadWrite;
    boost::thread m_ThreadRead;
    boost::mutex m_Mutex;
    boost::condition bufferNotFull, bufferNotEmpty;
public:
    ECG();
    void fillSample(int num);   //get sample from the data stream
    void processSample();   //process ECG sample, return the last processed 

};


ECG::ECG() : readyFlag(false), sampleIdx(0), readIdx(0), writeIdx(0)
{
    m_ThreadWrite=boost::thread((boost::bind(&ECG::fillSample, this, _1)));
    m_ThreadRead=boost::thread((boost::bind(&ECG::processSample, this)));
}

void ECG::fillSample(int num)
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_Mutex);
    while( (writeIdx-readIdx)%BUFFER_SIZE == BUFFER_SIZE-1 )
    {
        bufferNotFull.wait(lock);
    }

    sample[writeIdx] = num;
    writeIdx = (writeIdx+1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
    bufferNotEmpty.notify_one();

}

void ECG::processSample()
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_Mutex);
    while( readIdx == writeIdx )
    {
        bufferNotEmpty.wait(lock);
    }

    sample[readIdx] *= 2;
    readIdx = (readIdx+1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
    ++sampleIdx;
    bufferNotFull.notify_one();
}
```

I already included the placeholders.hpp header file but it still doesn't compile. If I replace the _1 with 0, then it will work. But this will initialize the thread function with 0, which is not what I want. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: I don't see this `_1` defined anywhere. Is it an identifier?

Comment: Did the compiler say anything interesting - error messages in the log, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Move the creation to the initialization list:
m_ThreadWrite(boost::bind(&ECG::fillSample, this, _1)), ...

`thread` object is not copyable, and your compiler doesn't support its move constructor.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. I had to write a separate method start to create the thread for member functions fillSample() and processSample().

Comment: @tonga what do you mean by saying " this doesn't work either"? Doesn't compile? What compiler error do you see?

Comment: OK, I figured it out by myself. Basically I need to write start() and join() methods to start the thread instead of initializing the thread in the constructor.